# Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined - discord

Tags: javascript, discord

I am coding a discord bot. The commands I'm having issues with is temprole and kick.
The ping command seems to work fine.

main.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command == 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'temprole') {
        client.commands.get('temprole').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login('token')
```

temprole.js

```
module.exports = {
     name: 'youtube',
     description: "give the member a temprole",
     execute(message, args) {

         if (message.member.roles.cache.has('798180573998612512')) {

         } else {
             message.channel.send('You dont have access to this command!')
         }
     }
 }
```

kick.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(messages, args) {
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (member) {
            const memberTarger = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
            memberTarger.kick();
            message.channel, send('User has been kicked');
        } else {
            message.channel.send('You coundt kick that member');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is my kick command.

```module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(messages, args){
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (member){
            const memberTarger = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
            memberTarger.kick();
            message.channel,send('User has been kicked');
        }else{
            message.channel.send ('You coundt kick that member');
        }
    }
}```

Comment: this is javascript, not java. And please edit your question to include all relevant details, dont post them as an unreadable comment.

Comment: In the code provided you never use the `kick`command and for the `temprole` command, you exporting it with the name `youtube`, this might be an issue

Answer (score 0):

In your temprole.js, the "name" property does not match temprole, therefore the commands collection will set the command name as "youtube". You then try to get the "temprole" command from the collection but there aren't any. The fix is to change your command name's property to "temprole".